# Powershell - Start Windows service with a parameter

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I need to start a windows service via Powershell with a '1' as a parameter, like below:

[image]

So basically I want to do something like this with powershell:

```
Start-Service _MyService 1 <- won't work
```

Googling has produced nothing of note on this, perhaps I'm looking for the wrong thing, but I can't believe it's not possible. Clues anyone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An alternative is to use the Get-Service cmdlet to obtain a service controller, and then invoke its Start() method.

```
# "ServiceName" != "Display Name"
$yourService = Get-Service "ServiceName" 
$yourService.Start(1)
```

If you need to supply multiple arguments (credit to @Mark):

```
$yourService.Start(@('arg1','arg2'))
```

Comment: In order to supply a list of arguments I had to use explicit array syntax in the `Start` call: `$yourService.Start(@('arg1','arg2'))`

Comment: Great solution. What if instead of starting the service with particular arguments once I want to update the service settings, to specify that "Start parameters" line? How to do that?

Comment: @Alex, I'm not sure that you can do this with the service object that you get back from the Get-Service cmdlet.  You can change the image path to include your arguments using the sc command, as shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/222238/how-to-change-path-to-executable-for-a-windows-service/252850)

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke sc.exe that allows starting services with parameters:

```
Invoke-Expression "sc.exe start _MyService 1"
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the fast answer. Sorry can't mark both answers as correct, but have an upvote. I flipped a coin and chose Tung's answer.

Comment: @BenPower Tung's answer is probably more correct even without a coin, because it is pure Powershell, as in my answer it calls command line for help

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is unnecessary. Just type the command: `sc.exe start servicename 1`.