# Having trouble passing Credentials to Start-Service in Powershell without getting an invalid argument error

Tags: powershell

I have script that I'm using within a batch file to run a script to start service that requires the user starting the service to pass in a username and password the service requires. An input box comes up and I am able to enter in the credentials.

```
$srvName = Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.ServiceName -like ‘myService’ }
Start-Service net -arg $srvName -Credential (Get-Credential)Out-File C:\a.txt
```

However, the services doesn't start, and in my outfile, I get the following error.

```
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Service], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

When I look, I find plenty of examples of setting credentials for a service using Powershell, but only one for doing what I want to do and it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: "[The service] requires the user starting the service to pass in a username and password the service requires."  What? That is not how services work.

Comment: Ok, how do they work?

Comment: All the command line arguments for a service are already saved with the service.  If the service need to run as a different user, you can configure the credentials that the service needs, but a service is configured to be entirely non-interactive.  If there *are* parameters you need to pass, you should do them in the Services control panel.

Comment: You *can* pass arguments like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337905/696808) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/143367/how-to-start-a-service-with-certain-start-parameters-on-windows), but I've never seen that used for anything other than one-time configuration changes and such.  99 times out of 100, you don't need parameters.  99 times out of 100 that you need parameters, you set them up once and leave them alone.  The problem with doing it on a command line is that it's going to expose the credentials because the command line is public information.

Comment: So, are you saying the service itself needs to run as a specific user, or do you actually need to pass credential information to the service, which is essentially guaranteed to be insecure?

Comment: I've worked with services before, but just let run under an account and forgot about them. This is requirement, he wants to be able to limit running the service to a few select individuals. So are you saying that an account should be set up to run this service, and give users access to run that service? That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe it to out-file

```
$srvName = Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.ServiceName -like ‘myService’ }
Start-Service $srvName -Credential (Get-Credential) | Out-File C:\a.txt
```

The error posted states `InvalidArgument: (:)` because it's interpreting `Out-File C:\a.txt` as a parameter for `Start-Service` hence the `InvalidArgument`.

Additionally, start service doesn't have an `-arg` parameter, and I'm not sure what the `net` is for.