# How can start a service from PowerShell and pass start parameters to it?

Tags: powershell, service

I'm trying to start a service from PowerShell with start parameters similar to: `-l "192.168.10.10"`.

Following the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337718/powershell-start-windows-service-with-a-parameter) hasn't helped.

Here's my code:

```cs
#start service
$slave = Get-Service -Name "My Service"
if ($slave.status -eq "Stopped") {
    $ip = Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias myInterface -AddressFamily IPv4
    $args = @('-l ', "`"$($ip.IPAddress)`"")
    echo $args
    $slave.Start($args) # doesn't work
} else {
    echo "My service is already running"
}
```

run results below, no useful error messages I'm afraid:

```
 -l
"192.168.10.10"
```

I have verified that the service starts ok if I give it the parameters manually in service manager. It takes a couple of seconds.

Comment: Have you tried using `sc.exe`?

Comment: No, I was hoping to use the Start method provided by the object returned by Get-Service to keep it entirely powershell. I'll try sc.exe. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The `.Start()` methods accepts an array of arguments, which usually indicates that no extra quoting is required, so I'd expect the `"` in your `"192.168.10.10"` argument to be misinterpreted as part of the _data_, not as _syntactic elements_. Try `$args = '-l', $ip.IPAddress`

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix. It's quite subtle so worth sharing.

The service I was starting didn't like the trailing space after the `-l`.

```
$args = @('-l', $ip.IPAddress) # works great!
```

Comment: Note that the trailing space in `'l '` wasn't the only problem: You also had extraneous _embedded_ quoting around the `$ip.IPAddress` value (`"\`"$($ip.IPAddress)\`""`). As an aside: you don't need `@(...)` for array literals in PowerShell: `$args = '-l', $ip.IPAddress` will do.